# C# code to change the font family of text block to embed font in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, truetype

My Windows phone 8 application should work in two languages english and Arabic.
I have embed the custom font in my application and set the content type to **copy always**.
The embeded font is **nazli.ttf**.

By default the application's language is Engilsh with default font family **Segoe WP**.
Whenever the user changes the application's language to Arabic, then i want to change the font family to embed font i.e. **nazli.ttf**.

```
if (Constants.selectedLanguage.Equals("English"))
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
            this.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;

            //Setting the Default Font Family for English
            title.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe WP");
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar");
            this.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;

            //Have to set the embed Font Family.
            title.FontFamily = //How should i mention the embed font here
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this blog entry I adjusted it to work from code behind:

http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/24/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-24-embedding-fonts/

Now I have this font in the Assets/Fonts, the syntax from passing in the path and name is the same as described in the blog post.

```
title.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Assets/Fonts/CFLifeIsADream-Regular.ttf#CF Life Is A Dream");
```

HTH

Comment: In that post we are setting the font family fixed. I wnat to set that embeded font in code behind file, not in Xaml file.